# How to access values defined in AsyncTask from an activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have code like this

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     addItemsOnSpinnerOrgaLevel();

      btn_getReport.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

            //How can i access map and list defined in orgaLevelTask(AsyncTask)???
             Like
             String option = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();              
            int orgaCode = orgaLevelMap.get(option);

            // Both are defined in AsyncTask ??

    }); //end of anonymous class

} //end of onCreate()

public void  addItemsOnSpinnerOrgaLevel() {

    orgaLevelTask  = new OrgaLevelTask(AccountReportActivity.this, spinner_orgaLevel, spinner_branch, txt_extra, txt_extra1);       
    orgaLevelTask.execute();

} //end of addItemsOnSpinnerOrgaLevel()
```

In AsyncTask onPostExecute() Method i have

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<OrgaLevel> result) {     
    super.onPostExecute(result);                        
    if (result != null) {               
        addItemsOnSpinnerOrgaLevel(result);                                     
    } 
    dialog.dismiss();   
} //end of onPostExecute()

 public void  addItemsOnSpinnerOrgaLevel(ArrayList<OrgaLevel> result) {

    orgaLevelElementslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    orgaLevelElementslist.add("All");
    orgaLevelMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    orgaLevelMap.put("All", 0);

    for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {

        OrgaLevel orgaLevelRecord = (OrgaLevel) result.get(i);
        String key = orgaLevelRecord.getOrgaName();
        String value = orgaLevelRecord.getOrgaCode();

        orgaLevelMap.put(key, Integer.parseInt(value));             
        orgaLevelElementslist.add(key);

    } //end of for()

    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(accountReportActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, orgaLevelElementslist);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner_orgaLevel.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    setSpinnerOrgaLevelListener();

} //end of addItemsOnSpinnerOrgaLevel()

private void setSpinnerOrgaLevelListener() {

    spinner_orgaLevel.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,long id) {             
            String option = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();               
            int orgaCode = orgaLevelMap.get(option);            
            subOrgaLevelTask  = new SubOrgaLevelTask(accountReportActivity, spinner_branch, orgaCode);      
            subOrgaLevelTask.execute();             

        } //end of onItemSelected()

    }); //end of anonymous class

} //end of setSpinnerOrgaLevelListener()
```

In the subOrgaLevelTask i also have the same hash map as in this class. You can see that what i am trying to do is, put a key value in spinner. So when my **btn_getReport** button get click then i get the value of the selected item. Like if **All** is slected then i get 0 and so on. This key value thing is working. The problem is when **btn_getReport** get click then how can i get the value of the selected item. Because i am filling items in a background thread(In OrgaLevelTask and SubOrgaLevelTask) and my button is in Activity. So how can i do that when button get click, then i get the values from the map defined in OrgaLevelTask and SubOrgaLevelTask ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, make them public in orgaLevelTask, and simply access them. orgaLevelTask should be a variable in you activity class. Have you tried it? any errors?

You must make sure orgaLevelTask members will be accessed in thread safe manner

Comment: Thanks by making them public i can access it, but how can i make sure that my orgaLevelTask members are thread safe? I am using this in my activity `String orgaLevel = spinner_orgaLevel.getSelectedItem().toString();
int orgaCode = orgaLevelTask.orgaLevelMap.get(orgaLevel);` and `branch = spinner_branch.getSelectedItem().toString();
int subOrgaCode = orgaLevelTask.subOrgaLevelTask.subOrgaLevelMap.get(branch);`

Comment: you must not allow GUI thread to access collection that might be created/modified in async thread. You can for example fill temporary collection in your doInBackground, and copy it to final collection in onPostExecute.

Comment: Hmm what i am doing is my web service returns me ArrayList. So after returning list i am using something like this in my onPostExecute() method `orgaLevelElementslist = new ArrayList<String>();orgaLevelElementslist.add("All");
orgaLevelMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();orgaLevelMap.put("All", 0);for (int i=0; i<result.size(); i++) {fill LIst, fill map}`. You mean to say i do all that work in the doInBackground() instead of onPostExecute() ?

Comment: Its perfectly ok to be in onPostExecute. onPostExecute is executed on GUI thread,so no GUI widget/control/whatever will be able to access collection causing data race

Comment: But you said `you must not allow GUI thread to access collection that might be created/modified in async thread` and onPostExecute() is also run on GUI thread. what do you mean by `to access collection` ? Here i am also accessing collection by creating map and list and filling it ? and all are executing in onPostExecute() means on GUI thread ?

Comment: I mean that two threads - in your case async and GUI, cannot access single collection instance at the same time. onPostExecute is executed after doInBackground. doInBackground is being executed in background thread as name implies.

Comment: hhmm you mean that my Activity is one thread and whole AsyncTask is another thread(including onPre, doInBack and onPost) ?

Comment: not exactly, your Activity is main GUI thread, your doInBackground in AsyncTask is being executed in another thread. But both onPre and onPost are executed in GUI thread

Comment: hhmm so i can say that Activity, onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() is one thread and doInbackground() is another thread ?

Comment: yes, doInbackground is executed from separate thread. Whole point of asynctask is to do some job on background thread in safe way, and also to not do it on GUI thread which would result in ANR (Application Not Responding) error.